# How to use the DICOM LUT decoder with gdcm in Python - passing buffers

Tags: python, c++, dicom, gdcm

I need to use the [GDCM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/) for converting DICOM images to PNG-format. While [this example](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/ConvertPIL_8py-example.html)  works, it does not seem to take the [LUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) into account and thus I get a mixture of inverted/non-inverted images. While I'm familiar with both C++ and Python I can't quite grasp the black magic inside the wrapper. The documentation is purely written in C++ and I need some help in connecting the dots.

**The main task**

Convert the following section in the example:

```
def gdcm_to_numpy(image):
    ....
    gdcm_array = image.GetBuffer()
    result = numpy.frombuffer(gdcm_array, dtype=dtype)
    ....
```

to something like this:

```
def gdcm_to_numpy(image):
    ....
    gdcm_array = image.GetBuffer()
    lut = image.GetLUT()
    gdcm_decoded = lut.Decode(gdcm_array)
    result = numpy.frombuffer(gdcm_decoded, dtype=dtype)
    ....
```

Now this gives the error:

```
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'LookupTable_Decode'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    gdcm::LookupTable::Decode(std::istream &,std::ostream &) const
    gdcm::LookupTable::Decode(char *,size_t,char const *,size_t) const
```

From looking at the GetBuffer definition I guess the first parameter is the assigned variable `bool GetBuffer(char *buffer) const;`.  I guess that the latter 4-argument version is the one I should aim for. Unfortunately I have no clue to what the `size_t` arguments should be. I've tried with

```
gdcm_in_size = sys.getsizeof(gdcm_array)
gdcm_out_size = sys.getsizeof(gdcm_array)*3
gdcm_decoded = lut.Decode(gdcm_out_size, gdcm_array, gdcm_in_size)
```

also

```
gdcm_in_size = ctypes.sizeof(gdcm_array)
gdcm_out_size = ctypes.sizeof(gdcm_array)*3
gdcm_decoded = lut.Decode(gdcm_out_size, gdcm_array, gdcm_in_size)
```

but with no success.

### Update - test with the `ImageApplyLookupTable` according to @malat's suggestion

```
...
lutfilt = gdcm.ImageApplyLookupTable();
lutfilt.SetInput( image );
if (not lutfilt.Apply()):
    print("Failed to apply LUT")

gdcm_decoded = lutfilt.GetOutputAsPixmap()\
    .GetBuffer()

dtype = get_numpy_array_type(pf)
result = numpy.frombuffer(gdcm_decoded, dtype=dtype)
...
```

Unfortunately I get "Failed to apply LUT" printed and the images are still inverted. See the below image, ImageJ suggests that it has an inverting LUT.

[image: Comarison of the two images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple solution, I would apply the LUT first. In which case you'll need to use [ImageApplyLookupTable](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classgdcm_1_1ImageApplyLookupTable.html). It internally calls the gdcm::LookupTable [API](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classgdcm_1_1LookupTable.html). See for [example](http://sourceforge.net/p/gdcm/gdcm/ci/master/tree/Testing/Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/Cxx/TestImageApplyLookupTable.cxx).

Of course the correct solution would be to pass the DICOM LUT and convert it to a PNG LUT.

---

Update: now that you have posted the screenshot. I understand what is going on on your side. You are not trying to apply the DICOM Lookup Table, you are trying to change the rendering of two different Photometric Interpration DICOM DataSet, namely MONOCHROME1 vs MONOCHROME2.

In this case you can change that using software implementation via the use of: [gdcm.ImageChangePhotometricInterpretation](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classgdcm_1_1ImageChangePhotometricInterpretation.html). Technically this type of rendering is best done using your graphic card (but that is a different story).

Comment: Thanks, tried but it didn't work. See my update to the question.